# Contourplot matplotlib with every n-th line a different color

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to create a contourplot in Matplitlib with every n-th line a different color then the rest? I would like to have this because this less contourlines are showing not enough detail, and all the same color makes it too crowded. For example:
[image: Galaxy without fancy contourlines]

Comment: Although I answered my own question, I would like to know if there is another, maybe built-in, or more pythonic, method.

Comment: This is offtopic for SO, but what is that a plot of?

Comment: It is a (x,y) density plot of simulated galaxy. The Galactic Bar is clearly visible, as well as some structure in the spiral arms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. You have to specify the colors for each level:

```
levels = np.logspace(0, np.log10(Z.max()), 100 )[30:80]
color_levels = ['r' if (i+5) % 10 == 0 else 'k' for i in range(len(levels))]
pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, locator=ticker.LogLocator(), colors=color_levels, levels=levels, lw=2, norm=colors.LogNorm(), vmin=1, vmax=Z.max())
```

Herein is `Z` the results of the `np.histogram2d()`. The underlying histogram2d is plotted with `imshow`. The `[30:80]` slice on the levels is to prevent cluttering in the middle and edges of the image.

Of course you can edit the `% 10` in the definition of `color_levels` to every integer of your liking.

This results in:

[image: Galaxy with red contourlines]

Comment: I replaced your `enumerate()` with the more direct `range()`: it is strange to get the level values, and build tuples when none of these are used.

Comment: @EOL I saw it. I replaced it in my own code. Thanks. It was indeed unnecessary to include the values of `levels`