# Add certain lines from contourplot in colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, colorbar

A follow-up question from my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166664/contourplot-matplotlib-with-every-n-th-line-a-different-color). I created red contourlines every 10 lines, but now I want to have these lines in the colorbar. I know that you can add the lines in the colobar by:

```
CS2 = pyplot.contour(X,Y,Z,locator=ticker.LogLocator(), colors=color_levels, levels=levels, lw=2,norm=colors.LogNorm(),vmin=1,vmax =Z.max())
cbar.add_lines(CS2)
```

(I don't think I need to specify all the variables here, it's just that you add the result from the `contour` function in the `cbar` thingy.

However, that will result in adding all contourlines to the colorbar, but I just want to have the red ones. Slicing them does not work:

```
>>> CS2=CS2[5::10]
AttributeError: QuadContourSet instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Is it possible to only add certain lines to the colorbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by myself, but not in the nicest way imaginable. I created two different contourplots, one for black and one for red lines. Only the red ones are given to the colorbar. It works, but it can be better, I think. The relevant part of the code is the following:

```
levels = np.logspace(0,np.log10(Z.max()), 100 )[30:80]
levels_black = [level for i,level in enumerate(levels) if (i+5) % 10 != 0]
levels_red =  [level for i,level in enumerate(levels) if (i+5) % 10 == 0]

CS2_black = pyplot.contour(X,Y,Z,locator=ticker.LogLocator(), colors='k', levels=levels_black, lw=2,norm=colors.LogNorm(),vmin=1,vmax =Z.max())
CS2_red = pyplot.contour(X,Y,Z,locator=ticker.LogLocator(), colors='r', levels=levels_red, lw=2,norm=colors.LogNorm(),vmin=1,vmax =Z.max())

cbar.add_lines(CS2_red)
```

This will produce the following image, exactly as I wanted:
[image: Galaxy density]